# Is it possible to specify the application version for website in the Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

There is a single-page application (website) that can perform its functions without updating (including from a local copy). It was connected (via Google Tag Manager) Google Analytics, I get data about the application functions usage (by triggers on buttons clicks). But in GA, "application version" is shown as "(not set)" in all reports.

Is it possible somehow to pass the version of the app from the site, or is this feature only for apps?

UPD:

It's GA4.

Unfortunately I tried do it in GTM via the "fields to set" and get failed. Now I can see appVersion in realtime report as parameter of event "page_view" or my custom events, but in regular reports application version still marked as "(not_set)".

Comment: Universal Analytics or GA4? For UA at least the documentation suggests that you can set the app version via  the respective field "appVersion" (which in GTM would happen via the "fields to set" interface tin the GA tag). Not tested, hence a comment, not an answer. Link to docs: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#appVersion

Comment: It's GA4. I'll try do it in GTM via the "fields to set".

Comment: Seems really weird that I have a GA4 account for a web app, and they have multiple default widgets based on "app version" with no data, and I can find literally nothing about how to set the app version.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it now, but I believe this parameter is indeed a standard parameter only expected on mobile applications (Android, iOS).

Therefore, you should not be able to see any values for it in default reports, unless you manage to send it as firebase does it for an app.

From the firebase docs, there is the event app_update (normally collected automatically on apps)  that expects a previous_app_version parameter. What you could do is to try to dispatch that event, with the parameter and see if thé version shows up in default reporting, but I would not bet on it.